# how can users have their private or virtual ports?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to make a server where users can connect and start their own private database server listening on port 9999. So the user logs in with ssh and port forwarding of port 9999 and starts the database server. Then the client can access the database via localhost:9999.
How can I make this port private or virtualize it, so that many users can do the same? All with their own database server instance and all using port 9999?

To clarify the use case:
-user1 connects to the server: ssh -L pc1:9999:server:9999 user1@server
-he starts the database server: dbserver
-the database server starts and listens on port 9999
-then user1 starts the database client on pc1: dbclient
-dbclient starts on pc1 and connects to localhost:9999 which is forwarded to server:9999 and accesses the database server.

now user2 is doing this:
-user2 connects to the server: ssh -L pc2:9999:server:9999 user2@server
-he starts the database server: dbserver
-the database server starts and listens on port 9999
-then user2 starts the database client on pc2: dbclient
-dbclient starts on pc2 and connects to localhost:9999 which is forwarded to server:9999 and accesses the database server.

So user1 and user2 have there private database server instance running. they do not share the database server.

I'm not the admin of the server machine so I don't habe root permissions.

Comment: The use case does not seem clear. If user A connects to the server using `ssh a@x.x.x.x -p 9999`, they get a shell on the server. They can run the database application using something like `db_app dataset action` without mucking with localhost ports. Alternately, if you want to use port 9999 for a wider-use API (instead of ssh access), then you don't need ssh login at all; the db_app server handles authentication and hands out tokens upon successful authentication. Use the authorization token with each action: `http://x.x.x.x:9999&auth_token&dataset&action`. None of this seems Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: It can be done at the network level if each db server is running on it's own IP address on the same server.  Or you could create a virtual ubuntu server with one of the many tools like VirtualBox, vmware, openstack, etc.  Otherwise you would need to specify what database you are using for a database specific solution.